# Is "...written by the author it claims to be and not by someone passing themselves for them" correct?

Tags: phrases, idioms, meaning-in-context

I have a question to this sentence:

> Sometimes you need to know if the book was really written by the author it claims to be and not by someone passing themselves off as them.

Is that correct? I am not sure about the usage of "passing off as them".

Comment: the correct expression is  'pass oneself off as someone else'
it is not clear if you are talking about ghost writers or just writers who illegally write under the name of someone else.

Comment: Thanks, of course. Could you advise how to rewrite to make it clear?

Comment: sure..but tell me what exactly you want to say....are you referring to ghost writers?

Comment: I want to say: Sometimes it is important to know if the document was written really by the person whose name is on it and not by some fraud who uses the same name.

Comment: ok, so you might say: It is important to know is the book is written by the original author or by someone else  who is writing  using the author's name.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no need to use this pass off as verb? I would like to use it :) I would like to see my original sentence corrected so I can learn.

Comment: ok: Sometimes you need to know if the book was really written by the original  author and  and not by someone else  passing himself off as the real one.   Hope this can help.

Comment: Thank you! It does help. Also the "claims to be" part is not correct?

Comment: Well, the book can't really claim anything. You would have to use it in reference to the author, eg, "who claims to have written it", but that makes the sentence unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: By the way, this question is pretty much a proofreading question, which is off-topic here. If you could edit the question to explain what points you are unsure of and why, then you will be more likely to get helpful answers that can help you in the future, rather than just one "right" answer for this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

"someone passing themselves off as them" is technically correct but it is very hard to read because the people that "someone", "themselves" and "them" refer to each take effort to keep straight.

A cleaner way to say this, with differences highlighted:

> Sometimes you need to know if the book was really written by the **accredited** author **instead of** someone **else**.

If you wish to use the idiom, "passing themselves off as" it could look something like this:

> Sometimes you need to know if the book was really written by someone passing themselves off as **the accredited author**.

The two primary changes are (a) replacing "the author it claims to be" with "the accredited author" which reduces the complexity of that clause and (b) moves the reference to the author to the end of the sentence so it can replace "them".

Now there is only "someone else" and "themselves" and they refer to the same entity. You could accomplish the same thing without using "accredited" but I find removing the extra "it" helps because moving "it claims to be written by" doesn't work very well at the end. Here it is with your original phrasing:

> Sometimes you need to know if the book was really written by someone passing themselves off as **the author [the book] claims to be [written by]**.

Comment: I'd use "credited" rather than "accredited" (since the latter, at least in US English, means something more like "certified by an independent agency")

Answer (score 0):

There are less verbose ways to say it - you could say something like

"Sometimes one needs to be certain that person listed as "author" is really the writer of the book, and not a fraud penning under someone else's name."